# Prolog: Kth Largest Element of a list

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog and trying to solve some of the exercises from the book "The Art of Prolog". Someone, please help me to solve Q 3.3.1.(vi), below is the problem -

Q. Write a logic program for kth_largest (Xs, K) that implements the
linear algorithm for finding the kth largest element K of a list Xs.
The algorithm has the following steps:

- Break the list into groups of five elements.
- Efficiently find the median of each of the groups, which can be done
  with a fixed number of comparisons.
- Recursively find the median of the medians.
- Partition the original list with respect to the median of medians.
- Recursively find the kth largest element in the appropriate smaller
  list.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: They already broke the problem down into steps. Which step are you having trouble with and what have you tried?

Comment: Yes I know the algorithm. But I am struggling to implement it in Prolog. As I have started learning prolog from last month. I am not able to break the list after every 5 elements and create multiple groups from it.

Comment: @user3756005 - That's actually really simple. Create a predicate that receives a list like `split/2` and then do this in your header `split([],[]). split([A,B,C,D,E|T], [[A,B,C,D,E]|Empty]) :-  split(T,Empty).` What this does is take the first 5 elements from the Head of the list, and passes the Tail on to a recursive function that does the same for the next 5 elements until the list is empty. Here's a short resource that explains well how [lists](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse13) work.